# Change label color MarkerClusterer

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I'm using [js-MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlearchive/js-marker-clusterer) for creating clustered markers on my Map. I'm using API v3.

I've managed to create clusters:

```
new MarkerClusterer({
    map: map,
    markers: markers,
    renderer: {
      render: ({markers, _position: position}) => {
        return new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {
            lat: position.lat(),
            lng: position.lng(),
          },
          icon: '/assets/images/bitmap/cluster-marker.png',
          label: String(markers.length),
          color: '#fff'
        });
      },
    },
  });
```

Is there a way to change the label color? It is 'black' by default.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, I found the sollution. It seems that `label` can be a object.

If fixed it by changing my label option to:

```
label: {
          text: String(markers.length),
          color: 'white'
       },
```